# How to put variadic arguments to vector of elements with inheritance?

Tags: c++, c++17

I use c++ 17 and have the next set of classes

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void fun() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void fun() override {
    }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    void fun() override {
    }
};
```

I would like to have a function ***process*** that accepts variable list of variables and returns a vector of **A** (a base class)

```
std::unique_ptr<B> b1(new B());
std::unique_ptr<B> b2(new B());
std::unique_ptr<C> c1(new C());
std::unique_ptr<C> c2(new C());

auto vec = process<A>(b1, b2, c1, c2);
```

For using **initializer_list** i have to know exact type of passed arguments.

I do not see a way to use viriardic templates because I do not know how to  unpack parameters correctly.

```
template <typename T, typename... Rest>
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> process(std::unique_ptr<T> t, std::unique_ptr<Rest>... rest) {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> A = process<std::unique_ptr<T>>(rest...);
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> B = process(t);
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> AB;
  AB.reserve(A.size() + B.size());
  AB.insert(AB.end(), A.begin(), A.end());
  AB.insert(AB.end(), B.begin(), B.end());
  return AB;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<T>>> process(std::unique_ptr<T> t) {
  return std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>{t};
}

template <typename T, typename... Rest>
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> process(std::unique_ptr<Rest>... rest) {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> vector;
  auto va = {rest...};
  for (auto el : va) {
    process(el);
  }
  return vector;
}
```

Is there the simple way to implement a function that accepts variable arguments and returns a vector?

Comment: Are you expecting a vector of `std::unique_ptr`s or just raw pointers? If you want `std::unique_ptr` you would have to move them into the vector, since it's not copyable.

Comment: I'd like to use std::unique_ptr. Could you explain what you mean about moving them into a vector? Does it mean that I have to use std::vector<std::unique_ptr> as an input of proccess method?

Comment: `std::initializer_list<std::unique_ptr<A>>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    virtual void fun() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void fun() override {
    }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    void fun() override {
    }
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto process(Args&&... args) {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> vec;
    vec.reserve(sizeof...(Args));
    (vec.emplace_back(std::move(args)), ...);
    return vec;
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<B> b1(new B());
    std::unique_ptr<B> b2(new B());
    std::unique_ptr<C> c1(new C());
    std::unique_ptr<C> c2(new C());

    auto vec = process<A>(b1, b2, c1, c2);
}
```

Note though that here we have stolen the objects owned by b1, b2, c1 and c2 and they have been moved into the vector. This can be a bit surprising for someone using your code.

Normally when you want to move or take ownership of something you want to make that explicit at the call site to avoid confusion.

We could enforce that here by taking our arguments by value. Then it will only be possible to call with `std::unique_ptr`s if the use `std::move` at the call site.

Something like this.

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto process(Args... args) {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> vec;
    vec.reserve(sizeof...(Args));
    (vec.emplace_back(std::move(args)), ...);
    return vec;
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<B> b1(new B());
    std::unique_ptr<B> b2(new B());
    std::unique_ptr<C> c1(new C());
    std::unique_ptr<C> c2(new C());

    auto vec = process<A>(std::move(b1), std::move(b2), std::move(c1), std::move(c2));
}
```

Now it's impossible to call the function without moving the original `std::unique_ptr`, so it will be clear at the call site that the contents of b1, b2, c1 and c2 has been taken.

Comment: Why `vec.emplace_back(args.release())` and not `vec.emplace_back(std::move(args))`? The `release()` can be a bit dangerous if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh. We have a constructor that does exactly that for us. That's better, thanks.

Comment: @super it is exactly what i was looking for. thank you.